# How to Transfer files between two Android phones using Wifi Direct to Download directory of Android phone and not to Package directory

Tags: android

The below line in my code transfers *.apk file to my package directory.

```
 final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + context.getPackageName() + "/wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + ".apk");
```

How to modify the same so that each time it gets downloaded/transferred to downloads directory of android phone. I believe Downloads directory is a default directory in each android phone.

Currently it gets transferred to package directory say for example "com.example.android.wifidirect"

EDIT I made based on Manish's Solution:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
                Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");
                String extStorageDirectory = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "Download");


File file = new File(folder,"wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".apk");
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "server: copying files " + file.toString());
                InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
                copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(file));
                serverSocket.close();
                return file.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: go through your android-sdk/samples/android-17 or 18/WiFiDirectDemo

Comment: The code which i attached is from 17/WifiDirectDemo. In which the files gets transferred to package Directory. My question is "How to transfer files to specific Directory in android phone. For Eg in Downloads directory"?

Comment: Please check my answer and change with yours.It will work for sure and please don't forget to give me up-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code-

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + ".apk");
```

**EDIT:** You can try this code also, hope it will help for create different name every time.

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "Download");
            File file = new File(folder, wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".apk");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**EDIT** On your specific demand..

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "Download");
            File file = new File(folder,"wifixyz-" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".apk");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "server: copying files " + file.toString());
            InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
            copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(file));
            serverSocket.close();
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But how to download files in Phone Memory. The above code "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()             .getAbsolutePath()" is for SD Card I believe. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No No it will save file in your phone memory Download folder. change your code and test it..

Comment: Ya right. Got it thanks. How to process it for SD card then? Aside I do have Astro file manager. In that am able to see the file which i transferred using wifi direct. But if i open phone memory by connecting it to PC using USB cable i am unable to see that .apk file in Phone when viewing from PC.

Comment: One more query. But each time it saves as Download.apk instead of the original file name. How to go about it.

Comment: it is inside Download folder?

Comment: I have edited my main post with the solution u provided . Pls review the main code which i posted and confirm whether it is fine.

Comment: When the open Astro FIle Manager and go to Download directory, I do see this file. When I try to share this file ,I want to make WifiDirectDemo also to be shown in the set of options (Like it shows WifiShoot, Bluetooth, etc set of options which are already installed apps). How to go about it. Does it involves major code modification? Am sorry if question is unclear.